# Unable to get category products on home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We are using a [buyshop theme](http://themeforest.net/item/buyshop-responsive-retina-magento-theme/4287671) from magento and trying to list a few products from every category on the home page by the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" block_name="Bestsellers" template="izotope/products_from_category.phtml"}}
```

The category above has more than 2000 products, however, nothing comes up. The normal category view via the menu works perfectly fine.

Also, tried using the default magento (1.9.2.2) code as shown below with no success

```
{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="your_category_id" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The same thing works perfectly fine on the localhost, however, we are unable to figure out any reason for such behavior.

We believe that it has nothing to do with the theme, it is something we are just not aware of or is probably disabled. We have tried everything including:

a. Clearing the cache

b. Checking the product status whether enabled and whether product is in stock

c. Checking whether the product is inside the category and the default store view

.....and many more small things but with no success.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: 1) check if category id on your local machine is the same as on your server. Maybe you are trying to use category id from localhost on your server
2) if you use cache accelerators like Varnish make sure cache is really cleaned

Comment: yes, the category id is different, cache is clear too. Have checked it multiple times.

Comment: 1) check if CMS page is Published, not disabled, 2) check if it is enabled for correct store view, 3) make sure url key of your CMS home page is 'home' and after that, 4) the most important - tell what you see if you enter url like http://yourmagentosite.com/home

Comment: Just updated the answer. Thank you very much for the contribution and sorry for the trouble as error seemed something related to theme and nothing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was because of some theme based element. I deleted the theme and tried the default theme and was working as intended.

Just finished re-installing the theme and that worked. I got a newer version from the website, probably they might have fixed it.

Thank you again for the contribution everyone. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="2" block_name="home.catalog.product.list" template="izotope/products_from_category.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing. It is really weird as everything above I mentioned works on my localhost.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Thank you very much for the contribution and sorry for the trouble as error seemed something related to theme.

Comment: Glad to known you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set permission for that block

Open Admin >> System >> Permissions >> Blocks >> Click on Add New Block Button

after that in Block Name filed add your block name = catalog/product_list

 and set Is Allowed = Yes
click on save block button.
after that
add your cms code in cms page or static block it work fine

If it work for you then vote it up

Comment: Just updated the answer. Thank you very much for the contribution.